# How to show there will always be a set with size n+1 of formulas which is not satisfable but any of its subset with size n are all satisable?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I originally wanted to try a construction way to find out a uniform pattern of one of such kind of set, but although when n = 1...4 are all true (found such sets), I didn't see a uniform way to construct it for all n. Do I choose the wrong approach? Aka, should I seek some relevant propositional calculus formula to prove it in a deduction way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, take the $n+1$ equations $x_1=0,\,\cdots,\,x_n=0,\,\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=1$.

Answer (score 2):

In propositional logic, you could use
$$
a,\quad a\to b,\quad b\to c,\quad c\to d,\quad\neg d
$$
when $n=4$ and generalize to other $n$.

Comment: Or along similar lines, use $a, \quad b, \quad c, \quad d, \quad \lnot(a \land b \land c \land d)$.